# How to store urls of files/images in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using aws s3 for storing files. There are two options to store urls of these files in mongodb.

1. Store full url of image eg: "https://aws.s3/path/key"
2. Store only key in mongodb and and calculate(using aggregation projection or mongoose virtuals) full path every time I fetch docs

I just want to know which one is better and why?

Comment: There is no "better", there's only "different". Note down (for yourself) which pros and cons each approach has, then decide which aspect you're concerned more with. Do you want to store fewer bytes but use more CPU cycles? Do you want all querying to be clumsy? We can't answer this for you.

Comment: In future I can move files from aws to google cloud then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to store only the key in the database. This is because, over the time your applications will evolve and will require operations such

- Mapping buckets to domain names
- Replication to different buckets
- Modifying bucket names
- Proxying & caching the buckets content through AWS CloudFront & etc.

which will require file data record changes in mongodb, if you store the full http url.